# Python Popen.subprocess Exit status 0, but program exits immediately after subprocess completes sucessfully

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to view live output from a subprocess in real time. I tried several methods here, but they didn't work for me. Now I have method that works, but it causes my program to exit immediately after it successfully completed the subprocess. I get a return code of zero. The command is being run inside a FreeBSD jail (like chroot), and actually works, it just exits before finishing the rest of the program.

```
 import os, sys, subprocess

 DEVNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')
 save = DEVNULL

 tick = re.escape("'")
 Jcmd = "jexec 1 sh -c '/usr/local/bin/aria2c --quiet=false -x 10 " + re.escape(links[1]) + tick
 proc = subprocess.Popen(Jcmd, shell=True)
 returncode = proc.wait()
 print "RETURN CODE: ", returncode
 sys.stdout = save
 print "THIS PRINT STATEMENT DOES NOT EXECUTE, PYTHON EXITS BEFORE"


OUTPUT:

Download Results:
gid   |stat|avg speed  |path/URI
======+====+===========+=======================================================
c28be0|OK  |       0B/s|/usr/local/MOUNTPOINTS/_DOWNLOADS/document.pdf

Status Legend:
(OK):download completed.
RETURN CODE:  0
```

Comment: You forgot to import os, sys, subprocess. This works for me if I fix that and change the command line to "ls" or "dir".  It exits because it reached the end of the program. If I add more code after it, that executes (except for print which executes but obviously doesn't do anything because devnull)

Comment: @Kenny, I didn't forget to import os etc., I just didn't include those in my sample. I have a whole lot of other code after this including a print right after the line sys.stdout = save that doesn't print, Python exits before that. Also, "ls" isn't a good test because the output I'm displaying is download progress and its very verbose. Anyway, its what's not happening after it finishes that's the problem.

Comment: Why are you using `tick = re.escape("'")`? That creates the string `"\\'"`, which may be right for a reason that escapes me, but it doesn't seem that it would close the opening `"'"` in `'/usr/local/...`.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the [mcve]. It looks like the second print statement does execute, however it correctly has no visible output because you told it to print to os.devnull

Comment: @eryksun I agree, but after various attempts, that's what ended up working for me in the end. The re.escape(links[1]) doesn't expand otherwise. Basically I have 3 nested commands. It all works, except continuing after it returns.

Comment: @Kenny, that make's perfect sense now! Thanks! This is actually part of my first Python program, can you tell me how I restore the output?

Comment: Restoring sys.stdout fixes the problem. This is what I added after "sys.stdout = save" to make it work: sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__   Thanks@Kenny for opening my eyes on that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Kenny pointed out, I had redirected sys.stdout and my program was actually still doing stuff after the sys.stdout = save. I added this line after that to restore output to the screen, sys.stdout = sys.**stdout**. So here it all is:

```
import os, sys, subprocess

 # Next 2 lines not needed
 # DEVNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')
 # save = DEVNULL

 tick = re.escape("'")
 Jcmd = "jexec 1 sh -c '/usr/local/bin/aria2c --quiet=false -x 10 " + re.escape(links[1]) + tick
 proc = subprocess.Popen(Jcmd, shell=True)
 returncode = proc.wait()
 print "RETURN CODE: ", returncode

 # Next 2 lines not needed
 #sys.stdout = save
 #sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__

 print "THIS PRINT STATEMENT DOES NOT EXECUTE, PYTHON EXITS BEFORE"
```

Comment: But in this code, save and DEVNULL are never used. The intent of having a save variable is to keep the original value of sys.stdout safe while you have it changed to devnull. Then you restore it later. See my answer.

Comment: You're right, I was following another example I found here. I commented those lines out, as well as the sys.stdout = save lines and everything still works correctly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to silence stdout during the execution of your other process, in order to prevent python output from mucking up the subprocess's output. However, that may have been unnecessary here, since your python code just waits, so it can't print anything anyway.

If you want to silence the python prints, then restore them, it would be more like this:

```
import os, sys
with open(os.devnull, 'w') as DEVNULL:
    save = sys.stdout # this is what you want to restore later
    sys.stdout = DEVNULL
    print "this prints to devnull (not really)"
    sys.stdout = save # restore the original sys.stdout

print "this prints to stdout"
```

Notice that save is just a temporary variable for the real sys.stdout, which you want to get back later.

Comment: I wasn't really trying to silence anything. The other methods I tried waited until the subprocess finished before burping out the final output. I wanted LIVE output, which the method I used worked the way I expected, at least until the subprocess finished. Everything works the way I expected now. Thanks!